# F-test value in significance test for Linear Regression; what is the value when R^2 is equals 1?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, r-squared, f-test

What is F-test value in significance test for Linear Regression when $R^2$ is equals 1?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you doubt it’s value?

Comment: Can you describe the *F*-test you are considering ?  And your thoughts about why that *F*-test would need further consideration if *R2* = 1 ?